# Passing arguments to a function inside another function

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

Here are two snippets of code. They do the same thing. My question is which one represents the best practice and what's the reason behind it. Many thanks to you!

---

```
function foo(x){
    bar();
    function bar(){
       var y = x + 1;
    }
}
```

---

```
function foo(x){
    bar(x);
    function bar(x){
       var y = x + 1;
    }
}
```

---

Comment: what you excepted ans ??

Comment: it largely depends on what the function does. sometimes it makes sense to use a parameter for the inner function; other times it does not. If you post an actual function I can help you a lot more effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second snippet of code is better because it is provide more code reusability and low coupling between your variable and functions. Instead of first code snippet you can also use below code but you yourself have avoided that because it is not a good approach. As far as performance is considered first code is better because you are not passing any parameter to your bar function and whenever you pass parameter to a function it consumes CPU cycle and resource.

```
var x=10;
.....
function foo(){
    bar();
    function bar(){
       var y = x + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the answer I was looking for — reusability vs performance!

Answer (score 0):

The example that you have given is quite unsuitable for your question. In your example, you can even just do this:

```
function foo(x){
    var y = x + 1;
}
```

But it really seems that your function doesn't achieve anything at all, and that even makes it harder for us. And to answer your question, it is **situational**; or it *depends* on the **problem**.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say best practice is whatever is easier for a reader to reason about, so for that trivial example it'd be this:

```
function bar(x) {
    var y = x + 1;
}

function foo(x) {
    bar(x);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

They're almost the same and it surely wont affect your application speed except if you are working on a really huge program.

However, in the sake of code readability, you should use the second option.

Also, in some languages like Java, where you can write and use static functions -> ex: foo.bar(x), you will not be able to write it like that. So if you plan to learn more and write better, just use the second one.